# Missing informations for the architect

Tags: logical-deduction, three-dimensional

An architect wants to plan the creation of a house, but he has only two perspectives, one from the left and one from the front. 
The house consists of concrete cubes. All concrete cubes must be connected.

> How many cubes does the architect need to build the house, at minimum?

**Perspectives, the left one is from the left:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the builder can't circumvent the laws of gravity, so every block must be supported by a block underneath it, the minimum is

> 8 cubes:
>
>  [image]
>
>  (looking from the front)

Without this assumption, the minimum is

> 7 cubes:
>
>  [image]

Comment: It's 1 or 2 more if all the blocks have to be connected by faces

Comment: Yes, if they have to be connected with their faces.

Comment: Hey, I'm posting here as I literally have no rep on Literature: I put the bounty on expectation that there will be better answers than the ones originally given. The other bounty reasons did not apply so I chose the 'exemplary' one. By far, as you have said is the answer by Christophe.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Gotcha, thanks! When I saw the "exemplary" reason I assumed you'd chosen one of the existing answers to reward. Not sure if you get notifications for new answers to a question you've bountied, so I wanted to ping you and make sure you saw the new one :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am aware that Rand Al Thor has already done the solution with 8 blocks, yet I found a solution that only uses 7 blocks. This solution is compliant with the rule that all the blocks have to be connected by at least one face.

> ```
>  N/A    N/A    N/A            N/A    N/A    N/A          N/A     block    N/A
>
> block   N/A    N/A            N/A    N/A    N/A          N/A     block   block
>
> block   N/A    N/A            N/A   block   N/A          N/A      N/A    block
>
>
>        Front                      Side View                    Back View
> ```

Comment: I think your solution is not quite right. If you place the cube in the middle at the bottom of the house it isn't connected to an other cube with a face. But if you are sure it would be helpful if you send a picture of your building from this website https://usecubes.com/design

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, I didn't realise that every single cube had to be connected to another cube if it was on the ground. However, would this not put Rand Al Thor's suggestion incorrect?

Comment: Yes, but @RShiels wrote a comment under his answer where he says that if all cubes have to be connected with their faces it would be one more cube, so I marked his answer as the solution.

Comment: So if they touch the ground, this does not count as a face being connected? It is still touching the ground so it is connecting with at least one face.

Comment: Touching the ground doesn't count as a connected face.

Comment: OK sure, thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1):

> 9 Cubes, assuming all cubes must be connected face-to-face, not corner-to-corner.
>
>  [image]